# Creating a round button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my wp7 app, I use C# to create user interface. I want to create a round button in C# not in xaml. is it possible to do that only in C# (not with the help of xaml) ? if yes, how to do this? and also please explain how to change a style of a button or any other control by using C# code?

Comment: Can you pls tell me why you want to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can but don't know why you'd want to. Much easier to do with styles. Even easier to use one from an existing toolkit.

There is a round button in the Coding4Fun Phone Toolkit.

Get it via NuGet or download it [here](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/)